# What do the exit codes of ntpdate mean?

Tags: linux, ntp

Running the ntpdate program on Linux when there is no active internet connection gives this message in the console:

> Exiting, name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution

The exit code of the program is 1 is that case. I can however not find what the exit code really means, is it safe to say that exit code 1 always correspondents with the above mentioned error?

Taking a look at [the docs](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/ntpdate.html) does not help me, it says the following:

> ntpdate's exit status is zero if it finds a server and updates the clock, and nonzero otherwise.

Can someone give me a list of all possible exit codes and their meaning?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running ntp? or are you calling ntpdate?

Comment: In this case I am calling the ntpdate program directly. I guess I was surprised by the lack of documentation regarding its exit codes.

Comment: ntpdate is actually depreciated and you should really use ntpd to keep your system in check. if you want some help with a config update your question & i should be able to help with something

Comment: I know, and you are right. But still the documentation is nowhere to be found regarding the exit codes of the ntpdate program. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I had a quick look as well and can't see anything relating to exit codes other than none '0' - your specific error indicates the server you tried to sync too couldn't be resolved. You may be able to find something if you dig through the source - otherwise I'm not sure... sorry

Comment: No problem, thanks for having a look! I might try and have a look at the source code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a look at the [Source Code of the ntpdate program](https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp/blob/1a399a03e674da08cfce2cdb847bfb65d65df237/ntpdate/ntpdate.c) I guess I can answer my own question.

No, exit code 1 does not always relate to the error `Exiting, name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Searching for `exit(1)` in the source code, I found 20 cases where the exit code is 1.

For anyone that is interested, the piece of code that causes the `Exiting, name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution` error message:

```
error = getaddrinfo(serv, service, &hints, &addrResult);
if (error != 0) {
    /* Conduct more refined error analysis */
    if (error == EAI_FAIL || error == EAI_AGAIN){
        /* Name server is unusable. Exit after failing on the
           first server, in order to shorten the timeout caused
           by waiting for resolution of several servers */
        fprintf(stderr, "Exiting, name server cannot be used: %s (%d)",
            gai_strerror(error), error);
        msyslog(LOG_ERR, "name server cannot be used: %s (%d)",
            gai_strerror(error), error);
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Error resolving %s: %s (%d)\n", serv,
        gai_strerror(error), error);
    msyslog(LOG_ERR, "Can't find host %s: %s (%d)", serv,
        gai_strerror(error), error);
    return;
}
```